# What to do with sandyavandanam water? Can it be drunk?

Tags: vedas, rituals, sandhyavandanam, health

Normally we throw away the water left over after sandayavandanam or pour it under a tree. Can I drink the water instead of throwing it away? Can it enhance my health? Also can others drink it?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can consume it just like we consume Prasada of deities. It is supposed to enhance your health or health of anyone who consumes it.

Quoting from the book ["Hindu Dharma"](http://www.kamakoti.org/hindudharma/part17/chap12.htm) which is comprised of various speeches by [Sri Chandrasekharendra Saraswathi MahaSwamiji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandrashekarendra_Saraswati).

> Arghya must be offered before sunrise at noon and at sunset. Once
> there was a man called Idaikattu Siddha who grazed cattle. He said:
> "Kanamar konamar kandu kodu adugan pohutu par. " "Kanamal/r" means
> before you see the sun rise and "konamal/r" means when the sun is
> overhead and "kandu" is when you see the sun before sunset. These are
> the three times when you ought to offer arghya. "adu" means "niradu",
> bathe in the Ganga. "kan" here means "visit Setu" or have " have
> darsana of Setu". "Pohutu par"- by bathing in the Ganga and by
> visiting Setu your sins will be washed away. Here is mentioned the
> custom of going to Kasi, collecting Ganga water there and going to
> (Setu) Ramesvaram to perform the abhiseka of Ramanathasvamin there.
>
> Only by the intense repetition of Gayatri shall we be able to master
> all the Vedic mantras. This japa of Gayatri and arghya must be
> performed everyday without fail. At least once in our lifetime we must
> bathe in Ganga and go on pilgrimage to Setu.
>
> **If a man has a high fever, people looking after him must pour into his mouth the water with which sandhyavandana has been performed.
> Today it seems all of us are suffering all the time from high fever!
> When you run a high temperature you have to take medicine; similarly
> Gayatri is essential to the self and its japa must not be given up at
> any time. It is more essential to your inner being than medicine is to
> your body.** Sandyavandana must be performed without fail everyday.
> Gayatri-japa can be practised by all of us without much effort and
> without spending any money. All that you require is water.
> Sandyavandana is indeed an easy means to ensure your well being. So
> long as there is life in you, you must perform it.

Also, yes, others too can drink it as the above passage in bold clarifies.